# How each call finds the variable outside a for loop which includes a inner function?

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6

Regarding the *let Declarations in loops* in book [Definitive JavaScript Developer guideline](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593277571), the code:

```
var funcs = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    funcs.push(function() {
        console.log(i);
   });
}

funcs.forEach(function(func) {
    func();  // outputs 0, then 1, then 2, up to 9
})
```

It says:

> The let declaration creates a new variable i each time through the loop, so each function created inside the loop gets its own copy of it. Each copy of i has the value it was assigned at the beginning of the loop iterations in which it was created..

I want to know, when invoke the function `func()`, how and where it finds the `i` value for each element in array of `funcs`. All element in `funcs` are same

```
ƒ () {
    console.log(i);
  }
```

Could someone illustrate how each step happens when call the function in the above code? (I sort of understand that, if use `var` instead of `let`, the global variable `i` is what each call finds.)

Comment: All elements are not same 
funcs.push(function() {
        console.log(i);
   }); here i will be replaced with iterating value i.e. 0,1,2,3...9

so you will get 

var funcs = [function() {console.log(0)}, function() {console.log(1)}....function() {console.log(9)}]; 

and forEach will just execute all these functions one by one